# Why running this env-cmd command is giving me this error?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I am trying to configure the local environment inside my project.

i am running `npm run dev` command.

here is my package.json

[image]

As you can see i am using `env-cmd` package.

But when i run the command window is giving me this error.

```
This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action...
```

[image]

Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post:

https://medium.com/@rishi.vedpathak/react-environment-specific-builds-using-env-with-cra-and-env-cmd-5960a1253fe6

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts start",
    "start:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts start",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build"
}
```

You are missing the **-f** parameter